# Peer/CA process when registering client . (node_eca.go)

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Can someone please explain the logic behind the following function :

**FileName:** [node_eca.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/core/crypto/node_eca.go)

```
Function : func (node *nodeImpl) getEnrollmentCertificateFromECA(id, pw string) (interface{}, []byte, []byte, error) {}
```

This function is executed during the "registration process".

I am a bit confused on how the key/certificate are generated and exchanged between the Peer and CA . Does the Peer generate the Public key and send them to the CA to store?or vice-versa?

Any assistance is much appreciated .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Every peer which would like to join Fabric’s network has to pass registration process. 
The workflow is:

1. At the beginning Peer should establish connection with CA (membership service) and confirm his identity by providing EnrollmentID and EnrollmentPass
2. Membership service will verify if provided EnrolmentID and EnrolmentPass are correct and registered in its database
3. Membership service generates Enrollment certificate (private and public keys) and sends them back to the peer
4. Now peer can sigh all messages with correct ECert

In this [document](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/protocol-spec.md) there is a description of enrollment process for user:
[image]

Peer uses the same approach during registration process.